# HTML and CSS div in middle of screen

Tags: html, css, center

```
   <style>
    .parallax {
        background-image: url("Cpage.png");
        min-height: 700px; 
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;

    }
    .box{ 
        position: absolute;
       top: 600px;
        left: 300px; 
       width: 900px; 
        height:600px;
        background-color:rgb(0, 32, 45);
         font-size:36px;
         border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .cap img{
       position: relative; 
       height:130px; 
       width:170;
       left: 340px; 
    }
</style>
<div class="parallax">
                <div class="box" >
                    <div class="cap"><img src="Capture.png"/></div>
                    <p style="color: white;text-align: center;">
                        LEARNING TOWARDS BETTER FUTURE!<br>

                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that when I switch screens. When I go from 15 inch screen to 13 inch screen the div moves. It is not in middle of screen anymore. May be it is because of the "left:" It really gets messy when screen is smaller then that. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you forget `.` in your CSS for parallax? You currently have `parallax` instead of `.parallax`.

Comment: my bad. It is actually right in my file. Let me correct it here.

Comment: no problem, just checking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex to help you center it:

```
 .parallax {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; // vertical centering
    justify-content: center; // horizontal centering
    background-image: url("Cpage.png");
    min-height: 700px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And remove `top`/`left` attributes from `.box`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dgdqcry/)

Comment: you can decrease height and width of .box and see it on fiddle. It is not in middle anymore.

Comment: It's in the middle of the `parallax` div. It seems not in the middle of the page, but that's only because your `parallax` does not cover the remaining space in height. If you want to do that, set it to 100% height and the body also to take up the entire height. Click the fiddle link, I updated it.

Comment: Thank you. The div is now adjusting to the screen. But I want the div at a specific vertical place in parallax image, when I said "top: 600px" I want it there but with your code, which puts the div in middle of screen only width wise not vertically. And one more thing! when you adjust screen, the image inside the div does not change its position, it is still there.

Comment: Not sure I understand which div you are referring to. I see the blue elliptic figure aligned vertically as well, are you referring to something else?

Comment: you are right, I dont want it to be vertically aligned. I want it to be at the bottom of parallax image... that is why I used top: 600 px;

Answer (score 0):

```
.box{ 
   width: 400px; 
    height:400px;
    background-color:rgb(0, 32, 45);
     font-size:36px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It is in middle but when i increase its width it is increasing from right side. Which makes it uneven. You can try and see. When I increase with to 70%  div increased towards right side.